# Update all items in a list using PowerShell

Tags: list, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with around 500 items. I need to create a PowerShell script that will call ALL of these list items, and then update a specific column (we'll call it 'Number') for EACH item.

The column (Number) that needs to be updated for each item is a Number column. I simply need to insert a random number into each list item, ranging from 0-100. It doesn't matter if numbers are repeated, but they need to be chosen at random.

I am very new to PowerShell and am still trying to understand the fundamentals. If someone could provide me with assistance around how to configure this cmdlet, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!

-Josh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the list you want to update is located at *http://YouServer/ListLocation/Lists/TheList*:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourServer/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["TheList"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item["Number"] = Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 100;
  $item.Update();
}
```

You need to execute this code in the *SharePoint 2010 Management Shell* or add the SharePoint PowerShell snap-in manually:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan! I may not have a chance to try this code until the weekend or next Monday, but I will let you know how it worked, and give credit where due! Thanks again :)

Comment: The answer is staright and simple. But what if there are more than 5000 items in that list ? Will this be an efficient way??

Answer (score 4):

You may try something like the following:

```
$list | ForEach-Object { $_.Number = Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 100 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response Joey. Can you give me a little more information around this please? I apologize, but I'm very new to this.

How do I set what list this will effect? And is $_.Number the display name of the column?

Thanks!